# Absolute minimum difference

Tags: algorithms

We are given a array of positive numbers. We can perform two types of operations on these sequence of numbers.

- If number E is even, then we can replace it by E/2
- If number E is odd, then we can replace it by 2E

We have to find the minimum absolute difference between any two elements after performing these operations any number of times.

Example 1: let the array of numbers be 1,2

Then we can replace 1 by 1*2=2

so the sequence becomes 2,2

Then the minimum absolute difference between any two elements would be 2-2=0

Example 2: let the array is 5,8

then we can replace 5 by 10 or(and) 8 by 4.

But for minimum absolute difference we will replace 8 by 4.

So the answer would be 5-4 =1

I am not getting any idea how to write an algorithm for it. Can anybody please help me in this.

According to me, the answer always should be 0 or 1.

Comment: Can you perform an operation multiple times on an element? For example, can you replace 12 with 3?

Comment: @xskxzr Yes, we can do it like that.

Comment: Can you explain what the output is when there are more than two elements?

Comment: First, make all numbers odd by dividing them repeatedly by 2. Then, for any two numbers, the minimum difference is attained by multiplying the smaller by the appropriate power of 2 so that the MSBs match.